# In python on OS X, how can I print and leave the cursor at the beginning of the same line?

Tags: python, macos, cursor-position

I would like my program to display some status messages as it runs, each one overwriting the previous. In Windows, I have been using the following to print a message and leave the cursor at the beginning of the line ready for the next message:

```
print message, '\r',
```

On OS X, however, this does not work - the cursor is at the beginning of the *next* line. It was suggested that I change `\r` to `\x1b[0G`, but this has the same effect.

How can I leave the cursor at the beginning of the *current* line?

Comment: Well, it's funny. Nowadays OS X is a real unix (actually, _more_ unix than e.g. Linux due to license issues and other non-technical stuff), so it has '\n' as line end and should support '\r' as `carriage return`, not `line feed`. So I guess it's a Python-specific "compatibility wrapper' behaves that wrong way. Could you test if a simple C program with a single `printf("Hello    world! \rGoodbye");` works as expected? If yes, you could use `ctypes` library to call libc functions directly. Currently I have no access to a OS X box to check it myself and reply as a real answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience - turns out `\r` works fine. The issue was caused by `message` being longer than a single line.

This never happened on Windows because I have a `Screen Buffer Width` far in excess of my `Window Width`, whereas on OS X it seems the two are always the same.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it in a Terminal window:

```
import time
import sys

print 'Hello\r',
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(3)
print 'There\r',
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(3)
```